# Tuple pattern matching on higher order function

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I would like to do pattern matching in the higher order function as the following:

```
.flatMapConcat { (raw, msg) =>

}
```

but it seems, it does not work. What am I doing wrong? Does Scala support pattern matching for Tuples in higher order function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `case`:

```
.flatMapConcat{ case (raw, msg) =>
```